# Attempting to iterate over a folder of .csv files in a directory using os.lisdir() to convert to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to iterate over many csv files and convert them to a pandas dataframe to manipulate, then send the manipulated dataframe back to a csv. I am able to do this with a single csv, specifying it's path. However, I am unable to get past listing the workspace that houses the csvs when using os.listdir(). Below is my code and associated error:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dir_name = 'C:/PA_Boundaries/Tests/'

dfs = []
for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    dfs.append(df)

print(dfs)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-c071588e1670>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/PA_Boundaries/osDIRtest.py', wdir='C:/PA_Boundaries')

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/PA_Boundaries/osDIRtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 462, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1050, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1867, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1368, in _open_handles
    storage_options=kwds.get("storage_options", None),

  File "C:\Users\mmulford\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 647, in get_handle
    newline="",

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Berks2_output.csv
```

The file for sure exists in the directory, so I am unsure how it's not able to identify it? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're using a relative path, but you need a full path. e.g. `Berks2_output.csv` vs `C:/PA_Boundaries/Tests/Berks2_output.csv`

Comment: huh, it's always something really simple and makes me feel dumb...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pathlib` you code will run correctly on both Windows and MAC OS:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

dir_name = Path("C:\\PA_Boundaries\\test")

dfs = []
for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(dir_name / file)
    dfs.append(df)

print(dfs)
```